# Определение пересечения нескольких сетей

Tags: java, алгоритм

Имеется массив сетей которые имеют два параметра - базовый IP и маска. Например

> netId = 1; baseIp = 10.1.1.0; mask = 255.255.255.0;
>    netId = 2; baseIp = 10.3.1.0; mask = 255.255.255.0;
>   ...

Проверять валидность IP-адреса применительно к конкретной сети я умею, решение простое.
Вопрос: как проверить на пересечение добавляемой сети с уже существующими?
Т.е. например если захочу добавить в выше указанный пример сеть с параметрами

> netId = 3; baseIp = 10.3.0.0; mask = 255.255.0.0;

То это будет ошибка, т.к. она будет являться более расширенной версией netId = 2.

Comment: в итоге /16 подсеть должно заменяться /24-ым ?

Comment: Нет, мне просто надо определить имеют ли пересечение две сети и если да, то ругаться и не давать добавлять ее в общий список

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сети не умеют пересекаться. Они умеют только входить одна в другую.

Проверка простейшая - для "пересекающихся сетей"

```
addr1 AND mask1 AND mask2 = addr2 AND mask1 AND mask2
```

Comment: Полное вхождение это вырожденное "пересечение"). Спасибо за ответ. Все действительно просто. Туплю(

Comment: Пересечение (когда для каждой подсети общей с другой подсетью является только часть адресов) возможно только для разреженных ("дырявых") масок. А их мало какие ОС, ПО и оборудование понимают... настолько мало, что можно даже не рассматривать. Поэтому практически всегда "пересечение" - это "вхождение".